# Spring Boot 2 and Cors Filter

Tags: spring-boot

Using `Spring Boot 2.0.2` - How do we suppress or hide `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header field in preflight response.

I have a custom `CORS` filter which adds this header to the response.This is a part of requirement for a penetration testing.Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `addCorsMappings` method of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to control what CORS headers are going to be sent to the client:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: The main point is that the allowed methods(GET,POST .. ) should still work for the client i.e the client should be able to send the requests(POST,DELETE..).The only intention is to just hide the "allowed methods" header to the client but the functionality should still exist(Just hide the header in server response).Kindly suggest if the above mentioned solution considers the same.